# Domain Url Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

What I'm looking to do is rewrite the url so that one of the directories are hidden.  For example;

```
http://www.example.com/home/example.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/example.html
```

As I'm new to .htaccess and mod_rewrite, is this something that can be done?

Comment: It's so polite when a post is voted down without a comment as to 'why'  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Cheers @Zak thanks for your post and also your comment not giving a reason for voting down a post.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't want to work for me!  That's not to say that it doesn't work but that I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^example.html$    /home/example.html    [NC,L]
```